# unable to update the submitData state value, failure of updating the state value because of asyncronous behaviour of js

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-functional-component

when i try to update my submitData using set submit it is showin {}, why i don't know the reason.there is the image.and in the console.log i am getting empty object {}. but the response is objected from the resuest as a boject with status.can you help me in this ?

```
const payload = {
    token,
    planet_names: selectedPlanets,
    vehicle_names: selectedVehicles
  };
  const response2 = await axios.post(
    "https://findfalcone.geektrust.com/find",
    payload,
    { headers }
  );
  console.log(response2.data);
  setSubmitData(response2.data);
  console.log(submitData);
  navigate("/result");
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}  };
```